# Receiver drier gasket doesn't seal for 1995 Dodge Ram 3500 Van

Tags: ac, climate-control

My vehicle is a 1995 Dodge Ram Van 3500 with a 5.9L V8. It uses a receiver drier like this one: https://www.oreillyauto.com/detail/c/murray-climate-control/air-conditioning---heating/accumulator-receiver-drier/receiver-drier-and-accumulator/429e999a7276/murray-climate-control-filter-drier/org0/303140/v/a/1681/automotive-van-1995-dodge-b3500

It takes a metal gasket like this one: https://www.autozone.com/cooling-heating-and-climate-control/a-c-gasket-and-seals/p/santech-mt0037-metal-gasket-10-piece-ac-gasket-and-seals/580319_0_0

This is a 134a TXV setup.

Does this gasket also require an HNBR oring, or should it seal on its own?

Also, I have not been able to find a torque spec for the nut that secures the plate to the drier. I looked through All Data and searched the Internet without success. The nut is probably a 5/16 flange nut. Do y'all have any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

The flat seal is made up of two parts; a metal gasket with an embedded rubber O-ring. This ac flat seal may be covered in a thin rubber or not. The metal portion serves to seal the metal ac fitting to the metal block of the receiver/drier. The embedded O-ring fits into the fitting tube  and block to seal against high pressures (operating pressures between 150-250+ psi). Flat deals are usually applied without pag oil lube. If you have alldata, read procedures. Presuming aluminum parts, firm hand tightening is all that's needed. Don't over tighten. The mating surfaces of fitting and receiver/drier block must be clean and free of dirt and mated with both surfaces in parallel to make a leak-free repair. Ac repairs are not diy friendly and require refrigeration knowledge.